# Drawing 3D plot from a matrix in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a some data in an exel file with 128 rows and 400 column.I am reading this Excel file into a Matrix with 128X400. Now I want to draw 3D Plott using presp in r.
Which parameters from this Matrix should be passed to persp?

**UPDATE**

I have this Matrix for example and I want to generate a 3D Plot, but I get an error:

```
k<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,62,25,2)
k<-matrix(k,nrow=3)
op <- par(bg = "white")
persp(ncol(k), nrow(k), k, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
```

Error:

```
Error in persp.default(ncol(k), nrow(k), k, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5,  : 
  invalid 'x' argument
```

Comment: provide reproducible example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: From your description, you already have a matrix (make sure it really is a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`, by using `class()`). Just feed that into the `z` parameter of `persp()`: `persp(z=foo)`

Comment: I have updated my post, @StephanKolassa thanks, I think you have answered my question

Comment: Read the help for persp? Why did you write what you wrote? Were you guessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reproducible example.

```
persp(z=k)
```

should do what you want. The help page `?persp` may be helpful.